complex integration gives result multiplied by i
I'm  trying to solve the following differential equation,
$$3\mu\phi\frac{d\phi}{d\tau} - \mu^2\phi = 0$$
where $\tau$ is a complex variable. I do this using the method of separation of variables to get to the following integral equation
$$\int d\phi = \int \frac{\mu}{3} d\tau$$
The solution to this that I have found is the following
$$\phi = \phi_0 + \frac{\mu}{3}\tau,$$
with $\phi_0$ being the integration constant. However my homework suggests that the solution should be
$$\phi = \phi_0 + i\frac{\mu}{3}\tau,$$
the only way I could see how this works is if the integration of $\tau$ somehow adds an $i$ to the solution.

Yours is right. There is no $i$.

Definitely a typo on their part. They might have meant $\phi=\phi_0+i\frac{\mu}{3}t$ with $\tau=it$.
